# VS2010 and SP2010, possible to have 2 list instances from 1 list definition?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to reuse my list definition to have 2 list instances of the same thing.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? If yes, could you post the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. The solution is this:

**Case 1. You have *ListDefinition* and *ListInstance* in one project.**

Add new *ListInstance* item into your project and set the same *TemplateType* property.:
[image]

**Case 2. ListDefinition already has been deployed**

You need to know TemplateType. Read this [post](http://sharepointryan.com/2011/07/06/use-powershell-to-find-available-sharepoint-list-and-library-templates/).